# Debugging a module upgrade

Tags: debugging, upgrading

In "Status report" I have message saying that some modules have database schema updates to install. However, when I run update.php nothing happens. I just get the standard error message that "Some of the pending updates cannot be applied because their dependencies were not met."

Reports -> log messages does not have anything relevant.

How should I debug this?

Comment: run `update.php`

Comment: I did that. Read the original post. I'm looking for a ways to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a module that you just updated now has a new module dependency. Go to your module listing page and see if any enabled modules now have a dependency listed as missing. Download the missing dependencies, enable and run update.php

Comment: Have checked the module dependencies in modules page. None is listed as missing.